# What's with the SE pulse survey and is the community OK with SE gathering personal data?

Tags: discussion, privacy

So first of all a "pulse survey" is basically a survey to factor user sentiment about something.   This is usually a product or something that a company sells.   How did we do then?   How was our product?   Feedback.

SE has a "pulse survey" and it isn't about SE.   It is an invasive survey about your gender, worth, work habits, race, and tons of other personal information.   That is not in any world a pulse survey.    This is the kind of crap Facebook used to do with its users to mine information.

Having this information is almost assuredly a violation of all [GDPR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/General_Data_Protection_Regulation) standards.   I can get into this deeply, but based on your SE account being logged in and the survey link there is almost no way that SE could store this information legally.   And to make matters even worse this was disguised as a pulse survey (what do you think about SE?) without any kind of warnings about your personal data.

Please understand that this is a common tactic for companies to make money on the back end.   You are logged into SE with [SSO](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_sign-on) (Yahoo, Google, whatever) and the linked account information with a trove of personal information is worth millions and millions.   I am just speculating, but at the same time there is no other reason why SE needs to know this information about you... and this is basically my area of expertise.

So if an SE moderator or employee responds I want to know the *full* details of how this information is stored, the timestamps, the session information stored and so on.   I actually was in a GDPR country so I could just make a request to SE corporate.

[Does SE understand what a pulse survey is?](https://diy.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1669/does-se-understand-what-a-pulse-survey-is/1670?noredirect=1#comment2239_1670)

Tech Details:

- Link: https://stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com/jfe/form/SV_4277sDd5RcbSY3I
- Link is only available to logged in users
- No disclaimer about how your info will be shared.
- based on my experience with these tools you can gather all of the user fields in hidden fields
- I have expertise in this area so please ask if you have questions or I need to add to this.

Please take a look at an example question below (after they collect personal info) and ask yourself if this seems like a *Pulse* survey and is this a question that SE needs to know.

[image]

Comment: Which survey are you talking about?

Comment: @VLAZ - I should have saved the link and maybe if I review my history I can find it.  It was in the banner and right hand side as "SE Pulse Survey".   I was on page 12 and still no questions about SE.   Just personal info, personal info, personal info.    Obviously SE doesn't need this to make a better site.       I will look for it later or if someone knows it, add it to my question.   (but then I would not want someone to take and save their personal info to SE so not sure I want people to know :) )

Comment: I find it really hard to take this post seriously when you've called out SE for violating GDPR/ breaking the law and then provided exactly _zero_ details to really back up your claim; it makes this post sound a bit... ridiculous, at least to me. The post would be way more coherent and easier to take seriously if you phrased it as a question about why the survey needs to exist and where the data is going, rather than an attack on the company.

Comment: I don't want to do the whole survey again  but is this the one that asks at the end about hacking in movies?

Comment: https://twitter.com/StackOverflow/status/1491412116733054982?t=SlvNV4ILBMlazxfvmylFUQ&s=19 links to the survey in question

Comment: _"Link is only available to logged in users"_ I just opened the survey in a private browser session (i.e., while not logged in) and it worked just fine. Am I missing something?

Comment: @41686d6564 - obviously they changed that requirement.  I can hit it now too.

Answer (score 12):

Surveys require your cooperation to gather personal information. If you are unsure whether your personal information will be handled appropriately, don't cooperate.

I was willing to cooperate initially, because it's very hard for me to turn down any opportunity to express my opinion, but as soon as I started wanting to not answer the questions I just stopped and haven't given it a second thought until right now.

I saw no evidence that the survey was surreptitiously collecting information I want to keep private. It's just the typical attempt to quantify the opinions of people about certain topics based on identity groups. We can argue about whether that's effective or necessary  but because it's completely voluntary to click the link and provide the information, I don't think it's nefarious.

I think the survey was too obsessed with identity, and not very interested in my thoughts, which is why I didn't complete it. It's not a good survey in my opinion, but the only way to put a stop to stuff like that is if people don't fill it out and they don't get their data. It's not illegal or evil to ask someone for information if they are truly free to not answer.

For the curious, the url for my session of the survey was `stackoverflow.az1.qualtrics.com` (I stripped the session information, it was expired). Qualtrics is a company I’ve encountered before doing these sorts of anonymous surveys.

Comment: And I block ads very aggressively on SE since their ad policy changed a while back. I don't remember the last time I saw a Google ad. The survey was an ad in the sidebar similar to a community ad. It could have been a third party ad, because I've been messing around with different browsers, but I think it's unlikely.

Comment: Collecting data by categories like race and gender imply that race or gender define people; people with the same skin color or gender are fundamentally the same, and fundamentally different from people of a different race or gender.  That's the definition of racism and sexism.  Why collect data in that way if there is no intention to use it to treat people differently based on their race or gender?  Why call it a pulse survey when it's not?  Is it nefarious if it's blatant and voluntary?  That's not the relevant measure.  It's kinda being evil.

Comment: @fixer1234 As an example, say you survey a bunch of people in a male-dominated sphere and find 95% think the culture is great, super inviting, best place to hang out, that sounds like everything is good. However, you break out the results by gender and find that while the vast majority of men indeed said that the culture is great, inviting, good place to hang out, a minority of your respondents were women and half of them said the culture is not great, not inviting, they were harassed regularly... Was the survey sexist when the results were interpreted by gender? Or was it something else?

Comment: @fixer1234 Like I said, we can discuss how creepy it is for people to be obsessed with immutable characteristics and identity, but in this case the solution is to not cooperate if you're not comfortable sharing that information. Not sure when it became evil to ask people to volunteer information. It's what you imagine their motives are that makes it nefarious to you. I try not to pretend I can read people's minds.

Comment: @BryanKrause, that tends to be largely artifacts.  There are far greater differences within each group than there are between the groups.

Comment: @fixer1234 It's a fact that gender and race differences in perspective exist. In the same way, there are differences based on what country you live in, or whether you grew up in a city or on a farm. Trying to see if there are any statistically significant differences by demographic is gathering information, not being *-ist. Trying to impose a group's stereotype on an individual is where things get evil.

Comment: @ColleenV,  I agree with you in the abstract. The problem is that this is another example in an ongoing pattern of divisive/creepy SE actions.  I don't want to sidetrack this thread, so I'll drop it. But your edit was good.  :-)

Comment: @fixer1234  Sometimes people (and companies, which tend to be made up of people with similar world views) have flaws that you can't fix. You have to decide whether the relationship is worth tolerating the flaw. The vast majority of US-based companies are obsessed with identity right now and arguing with them won't change it. Until things get less stupid I just refuse to engage with it. Everything is about engagement these days, so withholding your attention is how you make your displeasure known.

Comment: @ColleenV - very good answer.    Just FYI I forgot about the question because I was basically suspended from the site for arguing with a SE emp/mod that was obviously lying and I showed proof of what they were saying was incorrect.    I had become a somewhat expert in qualtrics.    It is almost insane the amount of meta data that they can grab in their surveys using hidden fields.   And the thing is you can put 200 hidden fields and just see what you get (out of someone's browser/cache info).    Awfully nefarious for something nothing to do with SE.   Marketing team defending it is pathetic.

Answer (score 11):

Chiming in from the Stack Overflow marketing team.

The background questions help us to ensure we’re getting a representative sample of the community. All responses are completely anonymous. No PII is collected. No data is tied to Stack Overflow/Stack Exchange user account information. No information is passed to any marketing database. We don’t sell the data. It’s purely intended for research purposes. To read more about the short surveys we run throughout the year, you can find out more here: [Short Surveys on Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/407610/short-surveys-on-stack-overflow)

Comment: Sounds good, perhaps a notice might be attached to the survey to that effect.... Personally I'd then be more likely to participate freely and honestly.

Comment: Great suggestion @ARogueAnt. -- we can absolutely add a link to more information on the front page of future surveys and underscore this information too.

Comment: @blankip It was a short survey, it was about 25-30 basic questions which required no thought and a few seconds each to answer. Perfectly in line with the 3 minute estimate they give at the beginning. No comment on the rest of your comment.

Comment: @blankip Opens perfectly fine in an incognito window, so no SSO session required

Comment: @JourneymanGeek - it didn't before.   Would get a weird message like I the link couldn't be reached.

Comment: @Nick - maybe we have different expectations on what "short" is.   Anything over 10 is for sure not short to me.   And for sure not a pulse survey.

Comment: I had the expectation that the survey would be feedback about Stack Exchange and their products, but it turned out to be a research survey. That sort of information is too valuable to just give away. I’m happy to provide feedback in exchange for an improved product or service. Anything else, like idle curiosity about whether I’m seeing a therapist, you need to compensate me. If I had understood that the survey wasn’t about SE, I would have never clicked on it.